# create some subdirectory in one directory

Tags: php, mkdir

I have this code

```
<?php 
function readFoldersFiles() {

    $arrayFolders = array("Circolari", "Comunicazioni varie", "Consuntivi gestione", "estrattor conto", "Preventivi gestione", "Regolamento condominio", "Verbali assemblee");

    $dir = '../pdf/'.$GLOBALS['condominio'].'/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

        //create subdirectory

        closedir($handle);
    }
}
?>
```

how can I create subfolders from the $arrayFolders

Comment: you just need for loop and mkdir method into for loop http://au1.php.net/mkdir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
<?php
function readFoldersFiles() {

    $arrayFolders = array("Circolari", "Comunicazioni varie", "Consuntivi gestione", "estrattor conto", "Preventivi gestione", "Regolamento condominio", "Verbali assemblee");
    foreach ($arrayFolders as $folder) {
      $folderPath = '../pdf/' . $GLOBALS['condominio'] . '/' . $folder;
      if (file_exists($folderPath) && is_dir($folderPath)) {
        continue;
      }
      mkdir($folderPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `continue;` instead of `break;`. Otherwise your script will stop processing when it found the first existing directory.

Comment: Yes.. sorry.. my bad! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $arrayFolders as $sub){
    mkdir($dir . $sub);
}
```

Word of advice: use absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

    function readFoldersFiles() {

        $arrayFolders = array("Circolari", "Comunicazioni varie", "Consuntivi gestione", "estrattor conto", "Preventivi gestione", "Regolamento condominio", "Verbali assemblee");

        $dir = '../pdf/'.$GLOBALS['condominio'].'/';
        if ($handle = opendir($dir)) 
        {

            foreach( $arrayFolders as $array_dir)
            {
                mkdir($dir . $array_dir);
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function readFoldersFiles() {

$arrayFolders = array("Circolari", "Comunicazioni varie", "Consuntivi gestione", "estrattor conto", "Preventivi gestione", "Regolamento condominio", "Verbali assemblee");

$dir = '../pdf/'.$GLOBALS['condominio'].'/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

    foreach($arrayFolders as $folder){

             if(!file_exists($dir.'/'.$folder)) mkdir ($folder);
           }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

}
?>